# Unable to stop VIM with Kill, Htop, or anything else

Tags: vim, process, kill, htop

I'm running Ubuntu Bionic. I installed SLiM display manager so my GUI uses tty2 and I ran vim to edit some C++ code in tty1. Suddenly, it froze completely. I tried to type things but nothing would show up. I used `ps -A` to find the PID of vim, but even `kill 14092` wouldn't work. I used `htop` and sent process `14092` a `SIGTERM`, but it hanged there. I sent it a `SIGKILL`, but it hanged there. **I even nuked it with a `SIGSEGV`, but it still hanged there!** How do I stop it?

Thank you very much.

**EDIT:**

I got it to stop after a reboot (well duh), but how can I do it in the future without the need for a reboot?

Comment: Did you try logging out? I.e. kill the parent, reap the zombie.  What state is the process in?

Comment: I tried htop and `ps -l`, but it wouldn't even show the process, only `ps -A` would ... ??? what is going on ??? ALso, normally zombies would die from being sent a `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: Did you press Ctrl + S during your editing?  if yes check this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72086/ctrl-s-hang-terminal-emulator#72092

Comment: No, I did not press Ctrl-S.

Comment: Could it be possible the terminal window itself froze and not vim ?

Comment: I said I'm using a TTY, not a terminal window.